# Android studio with aapt2 windows problems

Tags: android-studio, aapt2

Aapt2 error in android studio when generating apk
This problem started as soon as I updated android studio to 4.1.1.
I already uninstalled and installed it, I deleted it gradle I already did several processes and I couldn't solve the problem.

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD8np.png)

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform ccl-2.8.4.aar (com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:ccl:2.8.4) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a157a67bfc76ea22b4e9dc6044784dd7\jetified-ccl-2.8.4.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #2: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a157a67bfc76ea22b4e9dc6044784dd7\jetified-ccl-2.8.4\res\drawable-nodpi\album_art_placeholder.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-cast-framework-15.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:15.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f16f566ea15ba090a84a7c7a392d5912\jetified-play-services-cast-framework-15.0.1.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #1: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f16f566ea15ba090a84a7c7a392d5912\jetified-play-services-cast-framework-15.0.1\res\drawable-nodpi-v4\cast_album_art_placeholder.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\050caa3f0d7bdb092be2c6731bb1be21\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

Comment: aapt error occurs when there is an issue with the resource file.

Comment: I TRIED EVERYTHING, BUT WITHOUT SUCCESS

Comment: try to post some more file for understanding

Comment: Thanks for trying to help friend!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64947285/why-is-android-studio-failing-to-build-with-an-aapt2-error-on-images

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there must be some bug in windows or with the processor gradle 4.1.1 or 4.1.0 does not work and generates the error aapt2. As soon as I changed the version of gradle to 4.0.2 it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience with the newest `gradle 4.1.3` .  It is ALSO broken.

Tried `4.0.0` and everything worked fine, then saw this post so I tried `4.0.2` as mentioned by @Nicolas Alberto in the previous answer.  But the (working) compile with `4.0.0` gives me a deprecation warning:

```
"Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0."
```

Obviously, this is intolerable, but if you use 4.0.0, maybe your error will be solved, like mine did.