# Error when running the flutter run - AAPT2

Tags: android, linux, flutter, gradle, aapt2

I'm trying to implement mercadopago px, but at run time it returns an error
`AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-linux Daemon # 2: Unexpected error during compile`
I looked for some solutions [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64947286/2392241) , some say it is Gradle's mistake and others say it is related to the hardware. One of these solutions was to see the structure of the project and change the version of Gradle to a lower one, the version that did not give this error was (image), but there was an error in the main activity

Actual gradle

[image]

Changed Gradle

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have an older computer/laptop, it's likely the missing SSSE3 instructions. The bug was fixed in newer versions of AS/AGP so if you update your android gradle version to the newest 4.2 beta it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, really my PC is very old, AMD® Phenom (tm) ii x2 550 processor × 2 with 16 GB of memory.