# After setup OpenCV on my android project build failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, gradle, build.gradle

I got an error for **Build Project**, **Debug** & **Run**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

&

```
Dependent features configured but no package ID was set.
```

[My Android studio project screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c39hy.png)

**Tried:**
Invalidate and restart,
Clean Project

**Use:**
*Windows 10* & *distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip*

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64947285/why-is-android-studio-failing-to-build-with-an-aapt2-error-on-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest Version of **OpenCV** need to install.

https://medium.com/@kashafahmed/a-proper-beginners-guide-to-installing-opencv-android-in-android-studio-updated-5fe7f3399e1c